# The Federal Reserve is only issuing cash money?

Tags: federal-reserve, money

When the Federal Reserve is issuing money, they are only printing cash money (coins and banknotes)?

If not, then what other types of money they are issuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deposits at the Federal Reserve largely count as money, at least as far as the depositing commercial banks are concerned.

Apparently on March 1 2016, the Federal Reserve Banks' liabilities included $\$1475$ billion of Federal Reserve notes, net of F.R. Bank holdings, and $\$2530$ billion of deposits, together with $\$412$ billion of other liabilities. See the second part of table 5 of https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h41/current/ for more details

Coins are not issued by the Federal Reserve, but by the United States Mint

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand how much of that is cash and how much is non-cash

Comment: Deposits at the Federal Reserve are not cash but they are money: they  can be used for payment (at which point they become somebody else's deposit) and they can be converted into cash on demand

Comment: Thanks. Who and when takes the decision to convert the deposits into cash? I can imagine an answer for "when?": at the moment when many people decide to withdraw a lot of cash money from their banks accounts. The banks will transfer deposits to FED in exchange for cash? And what's the best term for these "deposits", non-cash money? Virtual money? Digital money?

Comment: The banks can demand cash for their "Federal Reserve balances" at any time, especially if they are ["excess reserves"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excess_reserves) as most of them currently are