# When in the history the governments issued non-cash money first?

Tags: money-supply, history

I understand that the Federal Reserve is issuing money in the form of deposits. Those deposits ["are not cash but they are money: they can be used for payment (at which point they become somebody else's deposit) and they can be converted into cash on demand"](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15644/the-federal-reserve-is-only-issuing-cash-money/15659?noredirect=1#comment24405_15659)

And then, my question is: when the history of the USA the authorities (government or FED or something else) issued such deposits instead of cash, for the first time? I have the same question for Europe.